# Can I use regex in properties file in JAVA?

Tags: java, regex, properties

I am trying to assert some text that is stored in properties file:

```
Text=\
some text\n\
to be\n\
asserted\n\
based on 1567 ratings
```

1567 vary so I want to make sure that it get's replaced with regex that will say that this can be any number using \d or \d, since I have to escape \ in properties file.

So I tried using

```
Text=\
some text\n\
to be\n\
asserted\n\
based on \\d ratings
```

this is the method I am using to assert:

```
Assert.assertEquals(PropertyLoader.loadProperty("filename.properties", "Text"),actual);
```

actual is a WebElement that gives me the text from website, I use `actual.getText()`

This is the class that has a loadProperty method

```
class PropertyLoader {
    static String loadProperty(String file, String name) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
           props.load(getResourceAsStream(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return props.getProperty(name);
    }
}
```

End result is that i am getting

Comparison Failure:

```
Expected:
    some text
    to be
    asserted
    based on \d ratings

Actual:
    some text
    to be
    asserted
    based on 1567 ratings
```

Not sure if this is even possible or I am simply missing something?

Comment: There's nothing to stop you storing a regex string there instead, but the `assertEquals` method doesn't try to match regexes - you'll have to use a different assertion.

Comment: You can probably add some logic to mark your property keys as regex-valued and attempt to load them as patterns, then invoke `assertTrue` etc. to try and match the pattern with a given `String` in that case.

Comment: You could use something like assertTrue(testString.matches(regex)). Btw, \d won't cut it, as it only matches one digit. You'll have to use \d+ or \d{4}...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the content of your properties file should be:

```
Text=\
some text\n\
to be\n\
asserted\n\
based on \\d+ ratings
```

Then your test case will be:

```
Assert.assertTrue(
    Pattern.compile(
        PropertyLoader.loadProperty("filename.properties", "Text"),  
        Pattern.MULTILINE
    ).matcher(actual).matches()
);
```